# Xcode: App Documents folder gets overwritten when re-compiled

Tags: ios, xcode

I am saving some images to the documents folder to make them available offline. It works perfectly until I recompile the app. As I can tell from some observations it seems like the documents folder gets overwritten / deleted then. This happens both in the simulator and on real devices. In the simulator the Application folder changes though.

My local file path:

```
let localUrl: NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!).URLByAppendingPathComponent("images").URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.chatId!).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

Is this behaviour intentional? What happens when I submit an app update in the future? Will old files get deleted then?

Comment: I guess you are trying to observe folder via terminal? This folder just moves to another directory

Comment: Nope. I printed the `localUrl` while downloading/saving the image and then again after compiling. It's the same path in both cases.

Comment: Yes, this is normal and it's not a problem unless you are mistakenly keeping references to absolute file paths instead of relative file paths.

Comment: @rmaddy but what happens later when I release an app update to the appstore?

Comment: Nothing you need to worry about. Again, as long as you never save absolute file paths, there is no problem. Always get the path to the Documents folder or whatever sandbox path you need at runtime, then append whatever needed relative path to that. As long as you do that, you'll have no problem getting access to the files within your app's sandbox.